# Hover Over Element not working on Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, mousehover

I have an automation infrastructure that works perfect on Chrome but having several problems with Firefox.
The problem I'm currently trying to solve it hovering over an element with `Actions`.
This method

```
public void hoverOverElement(By element){
    action = new Actions(driver);
    webElement = driver.findElement(element);
    action.moveToElement(webElement).build().perform();
}
```

works perfect with Chrome, but when used with Firefox the element doesn't appear to be hovered over it.
By hovering over that element several elements (buttons) are normally appearing there. Again, it works perfect manually both on Chrome and on Firefox and with Selenium on Chrome. But it doesn't work with Selenium on Firefox.
I have the latest version of Firefox and the latest version of geckodriver.exe
I saw in several posts here suggestions to set

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
```

however this gives the following  error

```
Cannot resolve method 'setEnableNativeEvents' in 'FirefoxProfile'
```

Will really appreciate any help!

Comment: what is `element` in your case ?

Comment: A `By` type locator. Again, it works perfect with Chrome. Some strange problem with Firefox only

Comment: By is abstract class isn't it ? What locator are you using ?

Comment: Mostly By.Xpath

Comment: Can you try css selector for hovering ?

Comment: These elements are located according to the texts. That's why I'm using Xpaths.

Comment: See, xpath engines are different in each browser so that could be something to improve here. css remains same in each browser. try if you could able to use css just for that hovering element

Comment: Well, it works correct with cssSelectors. However these elements can be located according to the texts only. Is there a way to do so with cssSelectors?

Comment: I think you should also add Java language tag